# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i)$.

Tags: statistics, summation

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i)$.

I fell into this hole where I keep finding that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x} = n\bar{x} - n\bar{x} = 0$$

This seems true, but I know that I am missing something, since this implies that covariance is always zero, which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)(y_i-\overline y)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i-\overline y\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-\overline x\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+\overline x\overline y\sum_{i=1}^n1=$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i-n\overline y\overline x-\color{red}{n\overline x\overline y}+\color{red}{n\overline x\overline y}=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)y_i$$

Comment: Definitely the hard way! $$ \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)(y_i-\overline y) $$ $$ = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)y_i- \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x) \overline y $$ $$
= \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)y_i- \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)\right) \overline y 
$$
(The step above works because $\overline y$ does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n.$)
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)y_i
$$
because the sum in the big parentheses is $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

For the first par:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})y_i-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})\overline{y}$. Since $\overline{y}$ is constant, we can bring it out of the summation sign, and as you remarked, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})=0$